# Working Of Php sessions

Tags: php, session

I am new to php and I want to understand the working of sessions in php ?
I know this is very easy, but i am new . Please give some answers ?

Comment: StackOverflow is more for direct questions and answers. For general stuff like this you can go to http://www.google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> session are used to track the value to
>   another page we use 
>   **session_start()** to start the session,
>   **session_destroy()** is used for destroy the session
>
> whenever we start session it generate
>   session id
>
> **http://w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp**
>   use this link for more detail

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that $_SESSION is an array exclusively associated with a given user's session in which you can store all kind of data

```
$_SESSION['test1'] = 'foo';
$_SESSION['test2'] = array('foo','bar');
$_SESSION['test3'] = array('foo' => array('foo1'=>'bar1','foo2'=>'bar2'));
$_SESSION['test3']['foo']['foo3'] = new Imagick($file);
```